# Linux find and replace

Tags: linux, shell

How can I replace `"abc"` with `"abcd"` on all files of a folder using shell?

Is it possible using `sed` command?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Explore the man page....

Comment: @Vikram.exe the man page doesn't explain anything about sed regexes though

Comment: @fge, there is a man page for that as well :)
or check: http://linux.die.net/man/7/regex

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try the following command for the file file.txt:

```
sed -i 's/abc/abcd/g' file.txt
```

Try the following command for all files in the current folder:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec sed -i 's/abc/abcd/g' {} \;
```

For the files in the current directory and all subdirectories:

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/abc/abcd/g' {} \;
```

Or if you are fan of xargs:

```
find . -type f  | xargs -I {}  sed -i 's/abc/abcd/g' {}
```

Comment: I need it for all files in a folder, not for single file

Comment: +1 for the find. because if the dir has subDir, those sed... * solutions will fail.

Comment: @Kent upvote my friend ^^^. find . -exec is very usefull anyway

Comment: If no recursive subdirectory search is intended, `-maxdepth` is advisable.

Comment: The replacement part can be shortened to `&d`, since `&` refers to the matched text

Comment: sed can cope with more then one file, what is the need for the file-construction?

Answer (score 3):

```
sed -i 's/abc/&d/g' *
```

should work.

Comment: It will also replace `0abcd`, `abcd` etc

Comment: yes, the question only states to replace abc. No indication about "whole words".

Comment: old question - but I found this useful in 2023! using the `*` is easier than filtering with file command IMO

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

```
find /the/folder -type f -exec sed -i 's,\<abc\>,&d,g' {} \;
```