# Change value of same variables in multiple code files

Tags: replace, find, fortran

I have multiple f90 files that contain the same variables

```
integer,parameter :: ilatmin = 0.5
integer,parameter :: ilatmax = 180
integer,parameter :: ilonmin = 0.5
integer,parameter :: ilonmax = 360
```

I would like to write shell script or a makefile where I specify the value of each variable and that loop through each .f90 file and update the values for each variable.

I though about using a search and replace like in this example [Linux find and replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588789/linux-find-and-replace) but was wondering if it's a good idea to use sed in a bash script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you put those parameters into a module that you `use` inside the `*.f90` files? It could look like:

```
module myParameters
  implicit none
  integer,parameter :: ilatmin = 0.5
  integer,parameter :: ilatmax = 180
  integer,parameter :: ilonmin = 0.5
  integer,parameter :: ilonmax = 360
end module
```

In your code you then can include that module, e.g.

```
subroutine foo
  use myParameters, only: ilatmin, ilatmax, ilonmin, ilonmax
  ! ...
end subroutine
```

Now you just need to change the module `myParameters`...

---

To your question... Using `sed` this could look like:

```
for i in *.f90; do
  sed -i -e 's/ilatmin = .*$/ilatmin = XYZ/g' \
         -e 's/ilatmax = .*$/ilatmax = XYZ/g' \
         -e 's/ilonmin = .*$/ilonmin = XYZ/g' \
         -e 's/ilonmax = .*$/ilonmax = XYZ/g' $i
done
```

Comment: thank you, great idea. Is the parameter 'only' needed?

Comment: No... but highly recommended ;-)

Comment: A general remark: an 'include' would also work. I know some of you will be upset by this remark because modules are more "modern", but it is important to recall that modules generate .mod files which are compiler-specific. This can lead to lots of trouble if you develop a library since it will force the users of the library to use the same compiler for their code *and* the library.

Comment: @AnthonyScemama I'm not sure how your comment fits into the context... You are correct, of course, that *headers* in C/C++ are much more convenient as modules in Fortran (with regard to portability), but we are not talking about headers or portability here... For a simple task as defining global variables a module is the best choice I think.

Comment: @AlexanderVogt but since this is something that many people will use and modify am I better off with a different solution? Because it is true they will need to compile the module as well.

Comment: This only poses a problem if you are writing a library against which external programs are supposed to link that don't use the same compiler. But even than I would rather use the `ISO_C_bindings` and write a separate C header file. Includes are (usually) clumsy in Fortran and I try to avoid them when possible. So no, for your case module variables/parameters are the best choice (in my opinion).